# Get the input of the Windows emoji-picker

Tags: c#, uwp, emoji

I made my own textbox in UWP, now I want the user to add emojis from the Windows emoji-picker window.

**The problem:**

When I click any of the emojis with my application focused nothing happens. I check the events that could get triggered by that but non of them got. I also tried it with the ASCII-emojis, but they also don't work.
I checked the CoreWindow_CharacterReceived event and the Paste event, but neither gets fired.

**The actual question:**

Is there any event I can use to get the input of the emoji-picker or is there a different way?

Github-repo:
https://github.com/FrozenAssassine/TextControlBox-UWP

Comment: I think you could refer to offcial text [editor](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CustomEditControl) to make your own cutom textbox.

Comment: Thank you I got it working with that. Would you like to add this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click any of the emojis with my application focused nothing happens.

The problem looks your TextBox is not in focus state, you could focus textbox manually after show Emoji pikcer. Then it will input emoji correctlly.

```
CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().TryShow(CoreInputViewKind.Emoji);
YourTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

**Update**

For customing textbox you could refer to [official](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CustomEditControl) text editor code sample that implement textbox with `CoreTextEditContext`.

Comment: I don't think, that is the problem, I tried your code, but it also did not work. My textbox is completely custom and uses the CharacterReceived event to update its content and renders it. So I think it is more a problem of the way I put content in my textbox than a problem of the focus. Also the clipboard history does work.

Comment: Well, but you have not  said you custom your textbox, (above code work well for native textbox )and Emoji picker has no such event could detect which icon you have pressed.

Comment: Ok, you are right, for a native textbox this code does work. Unfortunately, it doesn't for me. Thank you anyways ;D

Comment: You may share your custom textbox and I will test base on that to find if there is other solution.

Comment: I can share the GitHub link, but the codebase is not that small. Is this ok?

Comment: Ok, please update your case description above.